# jQuery function doesn't update data when it is updated in the database

Tags: php, html, jquery

I would like to update the data in the frontend when it is changed in the database. The code I'm using is given below:

```php
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.0.js"></script>
<div id="test">
    <?php
        include('conn.php');
        $query = "SELECT name FROM user_details WHERE user_id = 1;";
        if(mysqli_fetch_assoc(mysqli_query($conn, $query))["name"] == "MyName")
            echo 'Hi <b>MyName!</b>';
        else
            echo 'You are not <b>MyName</b>.';
    ?>
</div>
<script>
    setInterval(function(){
        $.get("/test.php", function(data){
            let $data = $(data);
            $("#test").append($data.find("#test > *"));
        });
    }, 1000);
</script>
```

However, when the data is updated, it does not get updated in the frontend unless refreshed. When I use jQuery's `load()` function, it works perfectly. Why does this not work?

Comment: Can you show me the test.php code or data response value?

Comment: @HoàngKiếm this document is `test.php`, for simplification purpose, this is the whole code.

Comment: I would advise using `.load()` and not `$.get()`. Most likely a Caching issue.

Comment: Also it's bad idea to load the same page into itself. I would make a stand alone PHP Script that you can call as an API that will provide the results in JSON or some other format.

Answer (score -1):

As I suggested in the comment, if you create a stand alone PHP Script, it might be like:

**getUserName.php**

```
<?php
$id = (int)$_GET['id'];
include('conn.php');
$query = "SELECT name FROM user_details WHERE user_id = $id;";
$myName = "";
if ($result = mysqli_query($conn, $query)) {
  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $myName = $row;
  }
}
mysqli_free_result($result);
mysqli_close($conn);
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($myName);
?>
```

This is a very basic example and I would **strongly** advise you switch to using prepared statements to avoid the risk of SQL Injection.

In your HTML you can now do:

```
<script>
setInterval(function(){
  $.getJSON("/getUserName.php", { id: 1 }, function(data){
    $("#test").append(data.name);
  });
}, 1000);
</script>
```

This will *ping* the script every second and you will have a list of names appearing.